# Problems updating the context within a loop? C.scene.update()

Tags: python, scripting

I'm using these loops to change the location of an object (I need to see how this object interacts with other objects in the scene when it starts from different locations).

Anyway, based on what's printed, the object's location is not updated in every "loop" repetition. It wasn't updating the location at all, I added the `bpy.context.scene.update()` line, and now it's only updating it once, so the output is always the same two coordinates (x=3 and y=2).

```
for ix in np.arange (3,50,0.25):
    for iy in np.arange (2,50,0.25): 
        bpy.data.objects["Ball.004"].location[0] = ix
        bpy.data.objects["Ball.004"].location[1] = iy

        bpy.context.scene.update()

        loc_ball=bpy.data.objects["Ball.004"].matrix_world.translation

        print(loc_ball.x, loc_ball.y)
```

How do I need to update the context (if that's the problem)?

Comment: What I don't quite get is what you're trying to accomplish, since multiple updates of the location will just be the same as setting it to the final location at once. If you intend to script an animation, you'll also have to set keyframes on the location and increment the frame.

Comment: In terms of what I'm trying to accomplish... I didn't copy the entire script here because the rest didn't add much to my question, but after the code I copied up there there are a few additional lines that get the coordinates of another object and copy those coordinates in a txt file. The idea is that I want the "Ball.004" object to hit a second object so the second object ends up at a specific location. That will happen only when Ball.004 starts from a few specific locations. I'm trying to find what the coordinates of those locations are.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. `np.arange` works correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "hit"? Do you intend to use rigid body physics? In that case your approach doesn't work, because of the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @rjg Yes, I'm using rigid body physics, but... I have the feeling that this could be related the keyframes as you suggest and I'll try a couple of things next, but what I'm trying to change is the initial location of the ball and that shouldn't be related to this, should it? After this, I'm copying the final loc of the second object, for which I understand I need to set keyframes. Indeed, I have a line in my code that does that before I copy the coordinates of the second object (bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1)) and that works fine.

Comment: @cildpolay if you're just trying to set the initial position, why don't you just set it right away? If you want to animate Ball.004 to hit another object using rigid body physics you need to assign its location at a specific frame a keyframe, so that it actually move there at that specific time when playing the animation later on. `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1)` is just setting the current frame, not a key frame. It's also a bit weird, because you set it past the final frame of the playback/rendering range. Not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: You were right, @rjg I was getting the last frame to get the coordinates of the second object at the end of the animation. The solution was to add a line at the beginning of the loop (bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_start)) to go back to the beginning of the animation. Thank you! thank you! thank you!

Comment: Does this now have anything to do with your original question?

Comment: Honestly, I'm done with this problem since it's working now, but blender doesn't make much sense to me anyway. So, I had the bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1) line to get the coordinates of the last frame and that was, but still the bpy.data.objects["Ball.004"].matrix_world.translation was stuck not in the last frame, but in the first frame of the first loop repetition..

Comment: @batFINGER yes. Sorry if the comments don't make sense. rjg and I deleted a couple of comments before so hopefully that didn't make this conversation confusing

Comment: Given the unforeseen _cryptic_ nature of this question, will  leave my answer as is, since IMO it answers the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe use matrix_parent_inverse * location**

Not sure what the issue is here.  The three values "np", "xx", and "tr" in test code below correlate.

Using `mpw * mpi * ob.location` avoids a scene update for each iter.

(*of-course if our parent inverse isn't Identity only the "xx" and "tr" values will match*)

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Matrix
ball = bpy.context.object
mw = ball.matrix_world
mpi = ball.matrix_parent_inverse.copy()
mwp = ball.parent.matrix_world if ball.parent else Matrix()
for ix in np.arange (3, 50, 0.25):
    for iy in np.arange (2, 50, 0.25): 
        #mw.translation = mw * Vector((ix, iy, ball.location.z))
        ball.location.xy = (ix, iy)
        print("np", ix, iy)
        xx = mwp * mpi * ball.location
        print("xx", xx.x, xx.y)
        # required or matrices don't update in loop
        bpy.context.scene.update()
        tr = mw.translation
        print("tr", tr.x, tr.y)
```

Last few results

```
np 49.75 49.0
xx 49.75 49.0
tr 49.75 49.0
np 49.75 49.25
xx 49.75 49.25
tr 49.75 49.25
np 49.75 49.5
xx 49.75 49.5
tr 49.75 49.5
np 49.75 49.75
xx 49.75 49.75
tr 49.75 49.75
```